# Class which extends Balana PolicyFinderModule

Tags: wso2, xacml, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I am Using Balana XACML for Authorization. Can anybody share with me a class which extends PolicyFinderModule of Balana to make PDP to Read a specified XACML Policy.
I want something as if we have SampleAttributeFinderModule, SampleResourceFinderModule provided by BALANA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think your requirement is to load the policy from In Memory. Balana has already implemented the concept of In Memory Policy Finder. You need a class which is extended from PolicyFinderModule. Check this : [SVN Link](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/trunk/commons/balana/modules/balana-core/src/main/java/org/wso2/balana/finder/impl/InMemoryPolicyFinderModule.java)

Comment: Thanks for the link. helped a lot